# How to get the multiple key from a single child value in firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the multiple keys from firebase real-time database using single value.
Main node is "Orders" then it has node of "userkey" then it has node of "orderkey". orderykey contains two nodes 'orderdetails' and 'orderitems'.

Now what i want is to get the 'userkey' & 'orderkey' using only the specific value present in 'orderdetails'.
[image]

I have tried it using two for-each loops but its returning all keys.
This is what i tried.

```
    myRef.orderByValue().equalTo("orderStatus").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.v("orderKey2", datas.getKey());

                for (DataSnapshot datas2 : datas.getChildren()) {

                    Log.v("orderKey3", datas2.getKey());

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

But its returning all the keys of first child and all the keys of second child.

**NOTE:** These keys are only push keys used for insert NOT firebase auth keys.

Comment: The above code you have won't work. You have to either use recyclerview to retrieve values from child of child element. If you have user uid by Firebase auth then it is possible to retrieve orderid

Comment: What you have wrote = `myRef`?